SwiftUI: Using onDrag on a LazyVGrid within a List?
It seems when using a LazyVGrid inside a List, the dragging behaviour breaks. Consider this:
List {
    Section {
        Text("Some section")
    }
    
    Section {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 32) {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text("\(item.id.hashValue)")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .onDrag {
                        self.dragging = item
                        return NSItemProvider(object: "\(item.id)" as NSString)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

Trying to drag a block of text results in dragging the whole section:

How do I prevent the surrounding list from hijacking the dragging behaviour?

This is kind of similar to how SwiftUI would simply find the first button in a List row and make that whole row perform the action of that button. It finds the first draggable view, and makes the whole list row draggable.
Unlike the buttons where you can specify a non-automatic button style to avoid this behaviour, there is no "draggable style" you can set.
A rather ugly workaround is to "hide" the fact that the view is draggable, from SwiftUI's "eyes" - introduce a layer of UIKit in between the draggable view and the list row. Wrap your view with a UIHostingController, then wrap that with a UIViewControllerRepresentable.
Here is an example with simple Ints being the items in the LazyVGrid.
struct ItemView: View {
    let item: Int
    let onDrag: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(item)")
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .background(Color.green)
            .onDrag {
                onDrag()
                return NSItemProvider(object: "\(item)" as NSString)
            }
    }
}

struct ItemViewWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let item: Int
    let onDrag: () -> Void
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIHostingController<ItemView> {
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ItemView(item: item, onDrag: onDrag))
        vc.sizingOptions = [.preferredContentSize]
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIHostingController<ItemView>, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.rootView = ItemView(item: item, onDrag: onDrag)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dragging: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("Some section")
            }
            
            Section {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [.init(), .init(), .init()], spacing: 32) {
                    ForEach([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], id: \.self) { item in
                        ItemViewWrapper(item: item) {
                            dragging = item
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: dragging) { _, newValue in
            if let newValue {
                print("Dragging \(newValue)")
            }
        }
    }
}

